# deploy default vue-cli project to github but not work

Tags: github, vue.js, configuration, web-deployment, vue-cli

here is my project address, i deploy it to the github, but i found index.html seem not work, only one div tag, maybe other source like css js doesn't load successful! But it works in local. I am new to deploy, here is my project link, please help me check the project:

https://github.com/programmer-eric/firstvue/

Answer (score 1):

Did you build your project before deploying it? This is maybe not a solution, but I can't comment just yet, don't have the points :P

Comment: yeah, I build my project before deploy it, after build the project, exist a dist folder, the index.html works fine in local, but I push project to github, this page doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, are you serving the dist folder via a, for example express server?

Comment: upvote... juste to help you reach the level where you can comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I solved my issue through upload dist folder files, it works.